# IntegerDigits including leading zero

Tags: functions

On the Wolfram Mathematica page on "IntegerDigits" , it says:

"By default, IntegerDigits includes no leading zeros:"

```
In[1]:= IntegerDigits[Range[0,7],2]
```

> Out[1]= {{0}, {1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}

I want IntegerDigits to include leading zero. For example, I want the following:

```
In[1]:= NewIntegerDigits[Range[0,8],2]
```

> Out[1]= {{0}, {1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

Notice that entries "{0, 0}, {0, 1}" and "{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}" are not generated in the original function. I need the sequence truncated to an arbitrary length (instead of 8), so `list[n_]:= NewIntegerDigits[Range[0,n],2]` for any n. I also need the function for general base number, e.g. `list[n_]:= NewIntegerDigits[Range[0,n],b]`

Question: How do I do this? Many thanks for this.

Another example of what I want (base 4):

```
In[1]:= NewIntegerDigits[Range[1,12],4]
```

> Out[1]= {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}

Comment: To clarify, I want the following list of infinite lists (for a general base, say, base 4)
 {{0}, {1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1 , 1} , {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1 , 1} , {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}, ...}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

how about

```
Flatten[Table[Tuples[{0, 1}, {k}], {k, 1, 4}], 1]
```

> {{0}, {1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 
>     1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0,
>      0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 
>     1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
>     1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 
>     1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

**EDIT**

```
Flatten[Table[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {k}], {k, 1, 2}], 1]
```

> {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 0}, {1, 
>     1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 0}, {3, 
>     1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The generalisation of this is exactly what I wanted, namely `Flatten[Table[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {k}], {k, 1, 4}], 1]`

Comment: nice! you're welcome

Comment: Just want to say again that I appreciate you and the other contributers' help a lot. This question was answered within the hour it was posted. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Minor variation: `integerDigitZero[base_Integer, maxLength_Integer: 2] := 
 Flatten[Tuples[Range[0, (base - 1)], #] & /@ Range[maxLength], 1]`.  integerDigitZero[4], for example

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you're seeking, and what "opposite" means here (since you want `{0}` and `{0,0}`).  But if you want each list element to have the same number of total digits, then try this:

```
PadLeft[#, 3] & /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 8], 2]
```

but if you just want to reverse the digits:

```
Reverse /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 8], 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Please ignore my sentence on "opposite". I want the generalisation, say, with base 2,

{{0}, {1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1 , 1} , {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1 , 1} , {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}, ...}

Comment: `PadLeft[#, 3] & /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 8], 2]` can be written more simply as `IntegerDigits[Range[0, 8], 2, 3]`

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not answer the question. I don't want to merely add zeros on the left of each list. In the example I gave, the bolded entries are not generated by `IntegerDigits[Range[0, 8], 2, 3]`

  {{0}, {1}, **{0, 0}, {0, 1}**, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Sort@Flatten[Boole@BooleanTable[Array[p, #], Array[p, #]] & /@ Range[7], 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
list[n_] := Flatten[Table[IntegerDigits[j, 2, i], {i,1,n}, {j,0,i}], 1];
list[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
This may be what you want.

b = 2; n = 4; IntegerDigits[Range[0, b^n - 1], b]

(*  {{0}, {1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 
  0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 
  1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}  *)

b = 4; n = 3; IntegerDigits[Range[0, b^n - 1], b]

(*  {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 
  2}, {2, 3}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
  2}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2,
   1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 
  0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2,
   1, 3}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 
  1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3}, {3, 1,
   0}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 
  2, 3}, {3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. This is not what I want atm, since "the entries "{0, 0}, {0, 1}" and "{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}" are not generated" in the proposed function.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
appendZeroOne[x_] := Map[Append[x, #] &, {0, 1}]
reproduce[xs_] := Map[appendZeroOne, xs] // Catenate
NestIntegerDigits[n_] := 
 NestList[reproduce, {{0}, {1}}, n - 1] // Catenate
NestIntegerDigits[4]
```

Out:

```
{{0}, {1}, 
{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1},
{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 
  1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
  1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 
  1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```